# Named Range Changes when cells are shifted up even though it is locked

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a named range of
`=OFFSET('Student Information'!$B$8,0,0,Lists!$B$3,1)`.

When the row is shifted up in a later routine this range will change to
`=OFFSET('Student Information'!#REF!,0,0,Lists!$B$3,1)`.

I need it to stay as the original. I have no idea why this is working like this.

Comment: I was under the impression that when you lock the cells with the $ it wouldnt change.

Comment: Sorry to say, if your job really depends on fixing one Excel formula, then you seriously need to reconsider your situation and look for alternatives. It might just happen any day you get a task you can't solve regardless whoever you involve.

Comment: You are probably right.

Answer (score 0):

I've tested your issue and for me it happens only if I delete `'Student Information'!$B$8`, and that's the expected behaviour.

If I delete column A or rows 1:7, then reference changes accordingly (e.g. after deleting column A it becomes `'Student Information'!$A$8`).

If you delete the referenced cell Excel doesn't know where do you want the new reference to be (if you want it at all), so it gives you error.

As a workaround you can use `INDIRECT`:
`=OFFSET(INDIRECT('Student Information'!$B$8,TRUE),0,0,Lists!$B$3,1)`
This will always refer to B8 regardless of the changes.

Comment: Yeah that is the issue, if I shift the first row of my database, which is B8 it will do this. Ive  tried this now and it doesnt seem to work still. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I just replaced it directly

Comment: Did you mean to use that as the named range in the name manager? Or something else?

Comment: INDIRECT isnt a function i have used before.